# how to locate the following HTML in selenium web driver?

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I have tried using class Name but it doesn't seem to be working .

How can I select `update` using span tag ?

```
<span class="ui-button-text">Update</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting 'update' can be achieved like this via xpath

```
"//span[@class='ui-button-text']/text()"
```

However I think what you mean is how can you get this text element, this would be more like this via css selector (assuming 'driver' is a properly started WebDriver):

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-button-text")).getText()
```

or with xapth:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='ui-button-text']")).getText()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
//span[text()='Update']
```